# Where can I find the source code for all the C standard libraries?

Tags: c

I'm looking for the whole source code of all the C standard libraries. That said, I'm looking for the source code of stdio.h, stdlib.h, string.h, math.h, etc... I would like to see how they were created. I think that it depends from platform to platform, but Linux or Windows one will be welcomed.

Comment: Do you want the header files (stdio.h) or the source code for the .lib and .dll files that implement the header files?

Comment: The .h files are not "the whole source code of all the C standard libraries", they're just the headers. So which is it you actually want? The header files come with your C implementation, but the definitions of the functions themselves may not be available to you if your C implementation is not open source. Even when they are available they might not be very instructive on their own, since in some cases a standard library function just calls an OS function to do all the work.

Comment: You probably want the GNU Libc http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

PJ Plauger wrote a [book about the standard C library](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131315099).  Includes references from the (now dated) standard, and source code.

Answer (score 28):

If you want the actual implementations, as everyone else has assumed you don't, many Linux distributions currently use [glibc](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/) to implement the C standard library. Common alternatives include [musl libc](http://www.musl-libc.org/), [diet libc](http://www.fefe.de/dietlibc/), [uClibc](http://www.uclibc.org/), and [Bionic](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bionic/)

Comment: uClibc says its releases are on hold, and one should use uClibc-ng https://uclibc-ng.org/

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft Visual Studio generally has the system headers under `<InstallDir>\VC\include`, and the source, if installed, is under  `<InstallDir>\VC\crt\src`.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for your problem.
Most of the responses you are getting are unnecessarily self complicated for nothing. Its quite obvious what you want:
The source codes for all the functions contained in the standard C library; And whose lumps include (of course) stdio.h, conio.h among others.
Well, you can get them around and as one zip file right here:

https://github.com/wuzhouhui/c_standard_lib

Good luck.
Love C.

Comment: what? what is in this? _**which implementation**_ of the standard C library? which version of that implementation? and which version of the standard C library?

Comment: also, any affiliation? [/help/promotion](/help/promotion)

Answer (score -3):

Whether its installed with an IDE or you have installed explicitly, you have to look in the directory "**`Include`**" in respective location.

Ex: I use MinGW. So, I would go to

`c:/MinGW/include` to find those header files. Similarly, for an IDE (say Dev-cpp), you need to go to c:/dev-cpp/include.